# GPIO pins will not toggle (high/low) on beagleboard xm

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboard, gpio

I am trying to use the expansion header to control a couple motors and auxiliary task mechanism. For this I am using the appropriate pins as GPIO and merely attempting to send high or low signals as needed by the robot. (For instance, I might need the robot to move forward and so I'd send high signals on both sets of pins, whereas if I needed the robot to turn I'd send a high signal to one pin and a low to the other.)

However, the problem is that the pins will only stay high! I've followed the conventions for sysfs just via the terminal, and, although I'm able to set the "values", "active_lows", etc. to 0 or 1, I can't actually get the pins to send 0V. After checking the beagle.h file I used for u-boot it looks like the multiplexer mode is configured correctly. This is also reflected when I get the info from sys/class/gpio/gpio%/% and sys/kernel/debug/gpio. Furthermore I don't get any errors or indication from anywhere that there is something wrong...it just doesn't work!

What should I do?  For the first time in my life I have seemingly exhausted the internet...

details:
Beagleboard xm rev c1
ubuntu 12.04
kernel 3.6.8-x4

Comment: You sure they are setup correctly? EG input/output and floating/pull-up/pull-down?

Comment: I'd also suggest double checking you have the pin you think you do: pins tend to get named for their default function (which is never GPIO), yet it's sometimes possible to route that line to anther pin.  This makes for a lot of confusion

Comment: the u-boot configuration is probably not primarily responsible for the peripheral configuration once the linux kernel boots.

Comment: @leppie
I'm fairly sure. Using cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio it looks like everything is configured right. Setting and checking /value for the individual gpios yields ostensibly correct answers as well...

Comment: @Marko
Oh man do I know this! But yes, I am fairly certain at this point because I've checked so many times with the beagelboard literature. (This is made easier because the pins are used for their default functions.) Thanks though.

Comment: @Chris Stratton
I was thinking the same thing, but in that case wouldn't the sysfs commands fail or return some permission error/error in general? As it stands now the results appear as expected.

Comment: Some other clarifying details I provided on TI's forums:
I've already checked my configuration file to ensure that the pins are in the correct mux mode. Furthermore, I'm using the gpio-sysfs interface for controlling the pins as described here. 

The gpio-sysfs files all indicate that it "should" be working, meaning i call _cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio_ and get the appropriate information back. But the voltage (as read by a voltmeter) continues to be 1.8V (across the pin in question and the grounded pins).

Comment: No, misconfigured, unclocked, unopowered etc GPIO typically does not result in any error message, since while these conditions might be undesired they are not erroneous.  You'd only get an error if the GPIO module where so misconfigured it was trying to access an address that was so incorrect as to cause a fault.

Comment: @derek if the OMAP3 documentation is anything like that for OMAP4, the datasheet (e.g. electrical and timing datasheet rather than TRM) is really useful for this.

Comment: @Marko
Thanks for the suggestion. I actually glanced at it but was put off by its complexity. Guess catering to my laziness is no longer an option!

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty new to the beagle board and I have recently been trying to configure the GPIO pins on my classic beagleboard c4, which i believe should be fairly similar.

Half of my GPIO pins seemed to work fine and the other half seemed to remain high or low no matter what i did. Even though they were configured the same way as the working pins in /sys/class/gpio/

have you tried to use other gpio pins?

I ended up following http://labs.isee.biz/index.php/Mux_instructions 
to configure the mux to 4 and now i can control the pins that were not working.

I basically used the command:

```
    sudo echo 0x004 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/(mux 0 name)
```

where (mux 0 name) was the name of the subsystem for the mux 0 setting for the gpio pin you wish to configure

ie. for gpio 183 on beagleboard c4

```
    sudo echo 0x004 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/i2c2_sda
```

Though I had to change permissions to modify these files

As I said I am pretty new to the beagleboard and ubuntu but this worked for me so I thought I would share it with you, I hope it is of some help.

Regards;
Paul;

Comment: _Have [I] tried to use other pins?_
Yes. However, I'm not sure they were configured for GPIO out of the box like 139 was. Also according the beagle.h file (from u-boot) pin 139 should be configured as input enabled, pull-up, pull* enabled, and mux 4, making the pin gpio, so all the pieces seem to be there...

Comment: ...I will try and implement the solutions from the site tomorrow when I'm back at school. However I have a couple questions from your instructions:

1. which set of instructions from the website did you follow? (kernel, those terminal commands, etc)

2. what permissions did you have to change? just running 'sudo su' seemed to work for me... (and you an see how that turned out!)...

Comment: Thanks Paul for all your suggestions! I'll report back here tomorrow!

Comment: I used chmod ugo+rwx /directory to modify permissions because I wanted to be able to access them as a default user so I could modify them at start up without any issues. I only did this because according to the site "when your system reboot or shutdown you will need to configure again". Following the first way from the site.  I am not sure if there is any drastic consequences of doing this(such as not being able to switch back to the default setting for the pin), but I figured I could easy recompile ubuntu if anything bad happened :)

Comment: you say it is input enabled, but you want to send signals to the robot? Maybe I misinterpreted the question but I am assuming you set the direction as output.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that the beagleboard expansion pins are numbered in alternating fashion, as clearly and professionally depicted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2skUt.jpg).**

Thanks to everyone for your help. I now know way more than I should about GPIO on OMAP systems (and so do you). Good luck on finals/life!**

***tl;dr I'm an idiot!***